# Algorithm to find the highest possible value on a curve

Tags: javascript, math

I'll be as specific as I can here without really knowing the method I'm looking for. I'm trying to write logic to solve this example I've come up with:

- I have $400 worth of Thing A, and $200 worth of Thing B
- I want to buy more Thing Bs for $100 each
- I don't want Thing B to exceed 70% of my total Things

How many Thing Bs can I buy? (can be fractional)

I know that for this example I need the maximum value of `x` where the following is true:

`(200 + 100x) / (600 + 100x)  < .7`

(the amount of Thing Bs I will have, divided by the total number of all Things I will have has to be lower than 70%)

However other than a brute force method of incrementing X by some small amount until this equation is false, I haven't been able to find the path to an actual formula to solve this.

Comment: The path to the formula is known as algebra. If you haven't taken algebra yet, then you'll have to wait before doing problems like this. In the meantime, the brute force method will work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an algebra question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem can be solved using easy math, which implies multiplying both sides with the bottom equation and solving it. For this, the total algorithm would be

- ((Percentage)(Cost A + Cost B) - (Cost B)) / ((Cost per B)(1-Percentage)).

If this case were solved logically without the algorithm, the result would be 200+100x = (600 + 100x)(0.7). 200 + 100x = 420+70x. 100x - 70x = 420 - 200. 30x = 220. x = 22/3. With this the algorithm can be deduced.

The value that we get is the maximum value, but since it's less than we then know x < 22/3, or the value that we would get from the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler approach:

You have $400 worth of A, and you want that to be 30% of your total assets.

So your total assets must be worth $400/(0.3) = $4000/3

You already have $600 worth of things, so the amount you must spend to buy more B is $4000/3 - $600 = $2200/3

So you must buy 22/3 B.